# Bode plot in ideal OA circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have this exercise:

[image: schematic]

I can do point 1 without any problems, but for example in point 2 I do not know what I should do with source V2 if the transfer function has to be computed only based on V1. Is it ok to end up with negative poles? Same problem with point 3: I know what should be done, but I have no idea how to set V1 if I am interested in Vo/V2. The not-very-reliable results at the bottom do not help either.

Comment: Please paste a schematic or a drawing as inserting a link is unpractical, thank you.

Comment: For 2 you can assume that V2 is constant, so a DC voltage. A Bode plot is a plot of the gain (or loss) which a signal experiences when traversing through the circuit. V1 is that signal and it cannot even reach the part of circuit to which V2 is connected. So at the + input of the opamp, there is no signal, only DC (if V2 is not zero). This is also a linear circuit so you can look at the transfer of V1 and V2 individually and add them at the output.

Comment: Source \$V_2\$ is silent in ac analysis (no modulation) so you can consider the (+) of \$A_2\$ grounded for the ac transfer function. For the transfer function, you see that you have cascaded stages with \$A_1\$ followed by \$A_1\$. Compute \$A_1\$ first and then consider the block starting at the left connection of \$R_5\$ with \$A_2\$ wired in an inverting op amp. By inspection, I can see that \$C\$ brings a pole and zero. For point 3, I would believe that if you have point 1 in dc already (output depending on two inputs), just set \$V_1\$ to 0 V and \$V_o\$ will solely depend on \$V_2\$.

Answer (score 1):

First, always post a proper schematic when asking here.  That includes putting the component values right by each part.  It's really annoying to have to look back and forth between the drawing and the chart.  It makes it difficult to "see" what is going on quickly.

You may have gotten the schematic this way, but that's not our problem and no excuse.  *You* are responsible for what you post here, no matter what someone else gives you.

As for the Bode plot, note that overall there is a high pass filter with one pole and one zero.  This comes from the interaction between C and R6.  At low frequencies C is open and there is only R6.  At high frequencies, R6 is shorted by C.  R6 being "shorted" is relative to R7.

You should be able to find the high and low frequency gains by inspection.  The rolloff frequencies then come from the interactions of C with R6 and R7.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a linear circuit, you can use superposition. So, for instance, consider the transfer function \$\frac{V_o}{V_1}\$, with \$V_2 = 0\$. Since \$i_{R2} = 0\$, negative terminal of the op-amp will be at potential \$V_1\$. For ideal op-amp, thus, the positive terminal of \$A_2\$ will also be at \$V_1\$. The current through R1 is:
$$i_{R1} = 0 = i_{R4}$$
Thus potential at output of A1 is \$V_1\$. Other end of R5 is at ground so:
$$i_{R_5} = \frac{V_1}{R_5}$$

This current flows through the series impedance of R7 and R6 || C, giving:
$$\frac{V_o}{V_1} = -\frac{1}{R_5}(R_7 + \frac{R_6}{R_6+sR_6C})$$
In a similar way, for V2 you have to consider V1 to be 0 and get the transfer function.